# How to plot compounded time series on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google, time-series

I cannot find any info on how to do this online

Let's say I have a spreadsheet of daily percentage changes as shown below, which D3:D11
[image: daily percentage changes]

How would I track how the compounded capital grows and falls on a daily basis assuming some starting capital?

So day one would be $1.009.

Day two would be (1.00946)(1.009)~$1.01854514.

Day three would be (1.00829)(1.00946)(1.009)~$1.027.

I then want to plot this as a time series but if it can't be plotted, I still hope to populate these values as a separate column. So E3 would be 1.009, E4 would be  1.01854514, E5 would be 1.027, and so on.